# Configure AWS S3 endpoint on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, amazon-s3, filesystems

How can I set the endPoint in the configuration file config/aws.php or config/filesystem.php to not get the following error

what is the name of the variable S3_END_POINT or just endpoint or what ?

```
The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint: "swiptimages.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable cause of this error is that you've created the bucket in different region than you put in S3 client configuration. Make sure that the value of **S3_REGION** (or whatever you're passing as region in **filesystems.php** matches that bucket's region in S3.